# Design for multiple classes, which implement multiple classes

Tags: oop

I’m looking for a pattern to design my application.
I have a fixed number of entities classes. E.g. PostEntity, ArticleEntity, DocumentEntity. They are all sub-classes of the abstract class ‘Entity’.
So far it looks simple. Today I got a new requirement: the implementation of the entities classes will be varies between the system, which means, we’ll have several systems: SystemA, SystemB, SystemC. Each system should implement its own PostEntity, ArticleEntity, DocumentEntity classes.

How would you create the classes in a reasonable way?

The simple approach is creating a folder for every system and put the classes in this way: SystemAPostEntity, SystemAArticleEntity, SystemADocumentEntity. And so on.
Then, maybe using Factory method to create the object. For example, to get the object of ‘PostEntity’ for ‘SystemA’, The factory should use switch/case of the Entity Type, and within this switch/case another switch/case of the System. This way doesn’t seem correct to me. I hope you have another idea.

Thanks

Comment: if you can only have one kind of system at a time, the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern may be applicable.

Comment: How is PostEntity different by system? What about it changes?

Comment: Ray, thanks, I'll look at this.
Bob, let's say the Entity class has a method of 'mapData' and each system should implement the mapping between this specific system and the central platform. In my case, about 80% of the entity code will be changed by the systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must deal with multiple entities and each one having a different set of behaviors per system you will most likely have an exponential class explosion. And I don't think that part is wrong, it is just representing the way things are. IMHO the only warning to look for here is if you start duplicating code.

Taking the subclassing approach seems ok to me for a start (i.e. having `Entity` >> `PostEntity` >> `SystemAPostEntity`). Then you can implement an [Abstract Factory](http://www.oodesign.com/abstract-factory-pattern.html), creating a concrete factory for each system. You would end up with something like:

```
abstract class SystemFactory
{
public createPost(params);
...
}

class SystemAFactory extends SystemFactory
{
public createPost(params) 
  {
      return new SystemAPostEntity(params);
  }
}
```

In that way each system would have a factory that will create the objects for it.

One thing to consider is if all the entities for a given system share some common behavior (e.g. they have to carry a timestamp and the behaviors related to it). In that case you should try to group that common behavior in one class and use delegation instead of replicating the code in every `SystemX*` class. Some languages have [Trait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_%28computer_programming%29) support, which may help you here to avoid coding the delegation.

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
yes.. I was concerned about the class explosion, but it seems that there is no other option. 
Using abstract factory in the way you mention, make sense to me, I thing I'll go this route.
Regarding trait, I'm using php 5.3 so unfortunately I don't have it, and I'm afraid that I'll need it.
Thanks!

Comment: @user2023637 In case the answer was helpful to you it would be nice to upvote or mark as solved.

Comment: Thanks Andres, I didn't know that I can mark it as fixed. Unfortunately I can't vote since I have less than 15 points.